# replacing HTTPget with basic auth credentials into libcurl

Tags: android, http, curl, libcurl

I am using Java DefaultHttpClient with basic auth in my android code as:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(getHost(), getPort()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(getId(),getPassword()));

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
```

The above code is using basic credentials for HTTPGet request.

I have to replace this code with CURL (libcurl) call.

I wrote a sample code to understand Libcurl calls.

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, webpage);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, HTTPData);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &page);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

But this is just basic CURL calls. How to incorporate the above http params and credentials into my libcurl calls.

I need to know how to write/modify the CURL code above to add the params and credentials of Authscope and USRPSWD credentials

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is a Java class that allows to make requests via http get/post with a basic auth. I am using this class in my android code. Now i have to replace it with CURL code. So i need to know how to provide basic credentials through CURL functions

Comment: anyone ... please give your responses.

Comment: i need to pass the parameters as shown in the java code for HTTPParams. e.g i need to pass the hostname, port,userid,password and timeout value.